# Qualtrics carry forward random subset - merging columns during data cleaning in R?

Tags: r, merge, subset, data-cleaning, qualtrics

When I created my survey in Qualtrics, I used carry forward randomization to have a subset of questions from a measure appear on the first page, then a random subset of the not yet seen questions are shown on the next page, and so forth. The end result is the long-ish measure is broken up onto 5 pages and the order of questions is completely random. It worked great! But the data comes out quite messy when exported as a CSV. Below is a reproducible example of just two blocks of the exported data.

```
reprex.data1 <- matrix(c("124", "Completely", "Completely", NA, "973", NA, "Moderately", NA, "592", NA, NA, "Completely"), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
reprex.data2 <- matrix(c("124", NA, NA, NA, "973", "Moderately", NA, "Completely", "592", NA, "Completely", NA), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
reprex1.cols <- c("id", "scale1_1", "scale2_1", "scale3_1")
reprex2.cols <- c("id", "scale1_2", "scale2_2", "scale3_2")
colnames(reprex.data1) <- reprex1.cols
colnames(reprex.data2) <- reprex2.cols
```

```
> reprex.data1
     id    scale1_1     scale2_1     scale3_1    
[1,] "124" "Completely" "Completely" NA          
[2,] "973" NA           "Moderately" NA          
[3,] "592" NA           NA           "Completely"
> reprex.data2
     id    scale1_2     scale2_2     scale3_2    
[1,] "124" NA           NA           NA          
[2,] "973" "Moderately" NA           "Completely"
[3,] "592" NA           "Completely" NA
```

I'm wanting to get the blocks of questions combined so that the survey responses across the five blocks get collapsed into one block. This seems like it should be relatively straightforward, but I can't figure it out with the different merge/join functions I'm used to using. Any tips? Below is what I'd like the data to look like eventually:

```
reprex.final <- matrix(c("124", "Completely", "Completely", NA, "973", "Moderately", "Moderately", "Completely", "592", NA, "Completely", "Completely"), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
reprex.cols <- c("id", "scale1", "scale2", "scale3")
colnames(reprex.final) <- reprex.cols
```

```
> reprex.final
     id    scale1       scale2       scale3      
[1,] "124" "Completely" "Completely" NA          
[2,] "973" "Moderately" "Moderately" "Completely"
[3,] "592" NA           "Completely" "Completely"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pivot_longer/pivot_wider` utilities from `tidyr` like this / also uses `dplyr`/`stringr`, so below I've loaded the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(
  pivot_longer(as.data.frame(reprex.data1), cols=-id),
  pivot_longer(setNames(as.data.frame(reprex.data2), colnames(reprex.data1)), cols=-id)
) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name,"_1")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = name, values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
  id    scale1     scale2     scale3    
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 124   Completely Completely NA        
2 973   Moderately Moderately Completely
3 592   NA         Completely Completely
```